# how to map to update an objects with setState in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have this state:

```
state = {
  formdata:{
    name: null,
    about: null,
    price: null,
    offerPrice:null,
    playStoreUrl:null,
    appStoreUrl:null ,
    photo:null, 
  }
}
```

**what I want:** update form inside modal i used it to update products. I used new props inside `componentWillReceiveProps`
 **I did:**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  let Updateproduct = nextProps.productlist.productlist.Products;    
  Updateproduct.map((item,i) => {
    let formdata  = Object.assign({}, this.state.formdata); 

    formdata.name = item.name 
    formdata.about = item.about 
    formdata.price = item.price 
    formdata.offerPrice = item.offerPrice 
    formdata.playStoreUrl = item.playStoreUrl 
    formdata.appStoreUrl = item.appStoreUrl
    formdata.photo = item.photo

    console.log(formdata)
    this.setState({formdata})

  })
}
```

**MyProblem:** this filled the objects but in the form inside modal only I saw the last product not all in modal when click to update any product it. **Note:**`Updateproduct` contains:

```
{
  about: "about product1"
  appStoreUrl: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snapchat/id447188370?mt=8"
  name: "p1"
  offerPrice: 99.99
  photo: "images/products/"
  playStoreUrl: "images/products/"
  price: 1000
}
{
  about: "about product2"
  appStoreUrl: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snapchat/id447188370?mt=8"
  name: "p2"
  offerPrice: 99.99
  photo: "images/products/"
  playStoreUrl: "images/products/"
  price: 2000
}
```

Comment: in state, you are maintaining a single object (one product), it needs to be an array in case of multiple products, and you seeing only the last product because at the end you are saving the last product details in state.

Comment: it needs to be an array in case of multiple ? what is it

Comment: its an object: `formdata:{...}`, it should be: `formdata:[{...}]`

Comment: the same problem one product repeated

Comment: can you show the update code, what you tried?

Comment: i just modified as you suggested... let Updateproduct = nextProps.productlist.productlist.Products;    
     Updateproduct.map((item,i)=>{
      let formdata  = Object.assign({}, this.state.formdata); 
     
      formdata.name = item.name 
      formdata.about = item.about 
      formdata.price = item.price 
      formdata.offerPrice = item.offerPrice 
      formdata.playStoreUrl = item.playStoreUrl 
      formdata.appStoreUrl = item.appStoreUrl
      formdata.photo = item.photo
        
      // console.log(formdata)
      this.setState({formdata})

    })      @Mayank Shukla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is, you want to store single specific product item clicked by user in state variable, but with current code you are always storing the last product item. Also setState in loop is not a good way.

To solve the issue, store the clicked product detail in state inside onClick handler function only, instead of `componentWillReceiveProps` method. For that you need to bind the product id with onClick function.

Like this:

```
onClick={this.getProductId.bind(this, item.id)}

// click handler function
getProductId = (id) => {
  let productObj = {};
  let Updateproduct = this.props.productlist.productlist.Products;
  Updateproduct.forEach((item,i) => {
    if(item.id == id) {
      productObj = {
        name: item.name,
        about: item.about,
        price: item.price,
        offerPrice: item.offerPrice,
        playStoreUrl: item.playStoreUrl,
        appStoreUrl: item.appStoreUrl,
        photo: item.photo
      };
      this.setState({ formdata: productObj, id: id })
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because your setState() call is in the wrong place (and only one object at a time):

```
let data =[];
UpdateProduct.map((item, i) => {
  let formdata = null;
  // do your formdata stuff but append it as part of an array
  data.push(formdata);
});
this.setState({ formdata: data });
```

Then I think it should get all the products.

Comment: it gave me not formdata not defined

Answer (score 0):

You’re setting your state inside the map. If you think of the map as a loop that means you’re overriding it each iteration. So you will only ever have the last one displaying.

Comment: so what the solution you suggest